# Android in app billing set product quantity

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Is there any way I can create one product in android market and depending on different buttons clicked by user to set different quantity of the product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know there isn't an option to send via android in app-billing quantity of one product, instead of this you can create for example three type of products, which will be something like that :

```
First Product : Quantity - 1
Second Product: Quantity - 3
Third Product : Quantity - 5
```

where all products are the same, just different quantities.